# Accessing Array from Function, React Native

Tags: react-native, api, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to access the elements of the array that I've called from the API. I have managed to call it, but how do I access and use the values in the array ? I am also not able to set the response to the `setAccountDetails` and the `setRecentTransactions`.

Below is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Colors, Fonts } from '../../styles/index';
import Header from '../../components/home/Header';
import BalanceCard from '../../components/home/BalanceCard';
import QuickActionsSection from '../../components/home/QuickActionsSection';
import {
  GetAccountDetailsResponse,
  TGetAccountDetailsResponse,
} from '../../models/home/AccountDetails';
import {
  GetRecentTransactionResponse,
  TGetRecentTransactionResponse,
} from '../../models/home/RecentTransaction';
import * as HomeServices from '../../api/HomeServices';
import { ThrowReporter } from 'io-ts/lib/ThrowReporter';
import { ApiErrorHandler } from '../../utilities/ApiErrorHandler';
import RecentTransactions from '../../components/home/RecentTransactions';
import OnloadRecentTransactionsAPI from '../../components/home/OnloadRecentTransactionsAPI';


export default function Home() {
  const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState([]);
  const [recentTransactions, setRecentTransactions] = useState([]);

  const getAccountDetails = async () => {
    const resultAccountDetails = await HomeServices.getAccountDetails();
    const responseAccountDetails = resultAccountDetails.body as GetAccountDetailsResponse;

    ThrowReporter.report(
      TGetAccountDetailsResponse.decode(responseAccountDetails),
    );

    return responseAccountDetails;
  };

  const getRecentTransactions = async () => {
    const resultRecentTransactions = await HomeServices.getRecentTransaction();
    const responseRecentTransactions = resultRecentTransactions.body as GetRecentTransactionResponse;

    ThrowReporter.report(
      TGetRecentTransactionResponse.decode(responseRecentTransactions),
    );

    return responseRecentTransactions;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      getAccountDetails(); //Call API here
      getRecentTransactions(); //Call API here
    } catch (e) {
      ApiErrorHandler(e);
    }
  }, []);

//Want to use 'balance' from the array in the API
  function totalBalance(accountDetails: any) {
    let totalBalance = 0;
    let total = accountDetails.accounts;

    for (var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
      totalBalance += total[i].balance;
    }

    return totalBalance;
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <View style={styles.greetingsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.greetings}>
            Welcome back,<Text style={styles.userName}> Natalie Tang!</Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
        <BalanceCard
          balance={totalBalance()}
          spent={data.spent}
          points={data.points}
        />
        <QuickActionsSection />
        <OnloadRecentTransactionsAPI />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Below is the shape of the response

````
accounts: t.array(
    t.type({
      username: t.string,
      accountNumber: t.string,
      accountType: t.string,
      productName: t.string,
      balance: t.number,
    }),
  ),

transactionsList: t.array(
    t.type({
      userId: t.string,
      type: t.string,
      currentAccountNumber: t.string,
      accountNumber: t.string,
      amount: t.number,
      notes: t.string,
      transactionTime:t.string,
    }),
  ),```
````

Comment: what error response when you cant store value into state ?

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal this one : Argument of type 'Promise<{ accounts: { username: string; accountNumber: string; accountType: string; productName: string; balance: number; }[]; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>

Comment: import React, {useState} from 'React', have you do it ?

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal yes yes I have. I've edited the code.

Comment: try at you state using this 

 const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState([] as any);

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal the error is gone, but when I console log accountDetails, I got this output {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Comment: how about log result at resultAccountDetails, is the same ?

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal do you mean responseAccountDetails ? if I log responseAccountDetails inside `getAccountDetails`, I get the right response, if I log it outside it, ReferenceError: Can't find variable: responseAccountDetails

Comment: can you edit when you setAccountDetail inside getAccountDetails ? i want to know how you passing the state

Comment: omg it works ! thank you so much !! I appreciate your help !

Comment: haa, i didn't do anything . your welcome

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal btw, while we are at it, why do I have to set it this way `const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState([] as any)` ? can I not set it as 'any' ?

Comment: bcz you were not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]> , you can set as Array, depend on your requirement. Are you using typescript on this project ?

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal yes, I'm using typescript.

Comment: the fastest way if u bit lazy you can passing useState([ ] as any) or you make interface for specifics checking type useState<IItem[ ]>([ ])

Comment: wait sorry, I have another problem. after putting setAccountDetail inside getAccountDetails , `my totalBalance()` works properly, but after a while, I got the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'total.length')`

Comment: you want loop result from total ?, why not using forEach ?

Comment: @FathurifkiElvariantoGamal I want to sum up all the balance in the accountDetails array. umm can you explain how to use forEach ?

Comment: can you give some sample data response ?

Comment: `{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "username": "Accenture",
      "accountNumber": "123456789",
      "accountType": "Savings",
      "productName": "Personal Savings",
      "balance": 400000000
    },
    {
      "username": "Accenture",
      "accountNumber": "987654321",
      "accountType": "Current",
      "productName": "Super Current",
      "balance": 400000000
    }
  ]
}` . I want to sum up all the `balance` and I'm expecting to get 800000000

Comment: upps sorry my mistake, we using map rather than forEach bcz we want create new Array. you can check my public gist [link](https://gist.github.com/fathurifki/a595866c96b4a4ff23cf38a8b8f3760b)